# Updated: antd Tooltip and navigation menu Tooltip flicker on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

We are using [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#header) (A  react component library ) in our applications and using a lot of the Tooltip, Menu and navigation menu components which are working great. However, we have noticed that all the tooltips in the applications flicker on mouse hover, which seem buggy.

**Here is  a code snippet for the Side Menu;**

```
 <Sider defaultCollapsed className='sidebar'>
    <Menu theme='dark' mode='vertical' className='sidebar-menu' selectedKeys={[selectedkey]}>
          <ItemGroup>
             <MenuDivider />
            <MenuItem key="scanbot">
              <Icon component={() => <ScanbotIcon />}/>
              <span>Scanbot</span>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem key="file">
              <Icon component={() => <FileIcon />}/>
              <span>File</span>
            </MenuItem>
          </ItemGroup>
          <ItemGroup>
            <MenuDivider />
            <MenuItem key="questions">
              <Icon component={() => <ResourcesIcon />}/>
              <span>Resources</span>
            </MenuItem>
          </ItemGroup>
    </Menu>
</Sider>
```

**Here is  a code snippet for toolTip component;**

```
 <Tooltip title="info">
    <span><Icon type="info-circle"/></span>
 </Tooltip>
```

I tried:

- updating the version of Ant Design to the latest version
- enabling the pointer-events style on the components
- running the applications on different browsers (Chrome, Opera, and Mozilla firefox)

All the above attempts haven't availed much success.

I have implemented these components in a separate project(personal) and they are working fine, I mean there is no flickering.

There is a possibility of this being an event bubbling issue, If it is so, how do I prevent it, given the fact that we are using antd?

Comment: We need some code, tools versions and as much deployment/production information possible.

Comment: it might be that your changing the state on "mouse over" and create lots of rerenders